# iphone app first tabview not showing tableview data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an App that has been working and selling in the App store for a while. I have decided to update it with a Webview.
The App has a Tabbar across the bottom, the first two Tabs are Navigation Views with tables in them that drill down. The third tab is the new web view, and forth is a simple image and text.

Starting the app, I don't see any table in the first tab, all others work fine. If I swap the two navigation tabs around the one that wasn't working on tab one now works on tab 2, and the other way round.

I'm guessing its something to do with how the app is starting and showing the first view?

Let me know what code you need to see?

***Answered myself in the end***

I managed to figure out it was a loading problem for the first view and changed my App delegate to reflect this:

**BEFORE**:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

**AFTER**:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I hope this helps someone else, it might not be the right way to do it, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: Ben can you make this statement clear ? "If I swap the two navigation tabs around the one that wasn't working on tab one now works on tab 2, and the other way round."

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
If I move the TabItem that has other other navigationController to be the first Tab, this doesn't load, where it did if it was the second Tab in.
Make sense?

Comment: How are you adding the tables to your view ?? programmatically or using the nib file ?

Comment: Add the tables programmatically to the first View because I think the issue is in that view itself.

Comment: Ok, this App worked fine the way it was set up, I'm using Xcode 4.4, so am thinking its possibly updated code that I haven't changed, I did have it working fine in the simulator, but not on the device at one point.
Making a few changes have allowed 'Tab2' table to start working, its just loading 'Tab1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered myself in the end

I managed to figure out it was a loading problem for the first view and changed my App delegate to reflect this:

BEFORE:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

AFTER:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I hope this helps someone else, it might not be the right way to do it, but it seems to work for me.